# Bug - Multifile Uploader Wordpress 4.0. Inifinite copies uploaded

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a media file in WordPress but when I select the file with the multiple uploader and the process starts, the progress bar stops at 100%. When I open the Library there are more than 200 copies of the file and none of them can be used in the website.

If I use the single uploader, everything works fine.

- How can I fix it?
- How to delete the copies in the library? I have more than 7000 elements!

Answer (score 0):

Yeess!! I found it's the WPML Media plugin that caused the media uploader to upload hundreds of times. This plugin is not compatible with WordPress 4.0.

Delete it and wordpress will work like a charm!